# Output of times (AM/PM) changed in Windows 10 when using DateTime.ToString("tt")

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, windows-10

I recently upgraded to windows 10 - and I'm now seeing some rather unexpected changes in the output of a date when using the "tt" format specifier.

Here's some code that demonstrates the issue:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cultures = new string[] {null, "en-NZ", "en-US", "en-AU", "en-GB"};

            foreach (var culture in cultures) {
                if (culture != null) {
                    var c = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = c;
                }

                DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, DateTimeKind.Utc);

                Console.WriteLine("selection: {0} CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: {1} CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: {2}  Value: {3}",
                    culture ?? "ambient",
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name,
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name,
                    dt.ToString("hhh:mm tt"));
            }
    }
}
```

The output in previous versions of windows was:

```
selection: ambient CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-NZ Value: 03:04 a.m.
selection: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-NZ Value: 03:04 a.m.
selection: en-US CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-US CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-US Value: 03:04 AM
selection: en-AU CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-AU CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-AU Value: 03:04 AM
selection: en-GB CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-GB CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-GB Value: 03:04 am
```

And in windows 10:

```
selection: ambient (windows 10) CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-US  Value: 03:04 a.m.
selection: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-NZ CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-NZ  Value: 03:04 AM
selection: en-US CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-US CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-US  Value: 03:04 AM
selection: en-AU CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-AU CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-AU  Value: 03:04 AM
selection: en-GB CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name: en-GB CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name: en-GB  Value: 03:04 AM
```

In both cases this code was compile win Visual Studio 2013 targeting .Net Framework 4.5

Does anyone know why the behavior has changed - and why in windows 10 it appears setting any culture on a thread specifically changes the output of AM/PM to be formatted as "AM" / "PM" not what is normally outputted for that culture?

Comment: Your code is running fine on my machine Windows10/VS2015/4.5.

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 language files installed for all the cultures you use here?

Comment: I have all the optional language features installed for en-GB and en-US... en-AU and en-NZ are just out of the box (but I do have them configured as languages that I can read and write with in windows 10). This is definitely a regression in behavior I think - also as I understood it, the CultureInfo data was loaded from internal windows calls, but came from data always available in windows e.g. the same info which populates the date & time settings dialog as you switch between countries.

Comment: what if you remove the language pack for en-NZ and en-GB?

Comment: Even if you "target" .NET 4.5, on your Windows 10 machine the BCL will be .NET 4.6. As far as I know it is an in-place replacement of the earlier .NET versions, as it has been since .NET 4.0. I wonder what will happen if you install .NET 4.6 on a machine running Windows 8.1 or 8 or 7 or Vista? Have your tried that?

Comment: Asking on behalf of @Shawn Steele: The "Previous version" output shows `en-GB` returning `am`. Which versions of Windows and .NET are you using? When I try I see `AM`.

Comment: If you add this:
`var ensureFormat = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;`
... after setting CurrentCulture, does that affect anything?
(Reading .NET code in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1433, this forces an internal field to be set which may then affect DateTime.ToString() : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs,520 )

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at "Culture Data Shouldn't Be Considered Stable" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2005/04/05/405694.aspx

One bit is that we started leveraging CLDR (Common Locale Data Repository, http://cldr.unicode.org) for many locales to better align with the industry standards.  You may have noticed that there are quite a few additional locales we now have data for.

Answer (score 0):

I always force to use `ToString("G")` when changing DateTime to string with `ToString()` function . Then I have no problems to parse the string to DateTime again. I tested it with my client application (gets date & time in XML in "G" format and parses it to DateTime) on Windows 7/8/10.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the combination of 'en-nz' and Windows 10 upgrade suddenly change `a.m./p.m.`to `AM/PM`.

The difference is the code I maintained relaying on `ToShortTimeString()` output with `a.m./p.m.` but in Windows 10 it changes to `AM/PM` instead I spend ages trying to find the correct culture info/format string, and I am also trying to find the missing local setting on my new Windows 10 machine compare to my old Windows 7 machine. But it turns out that the same local setting on different version of Windows machine does indeed display `a.m./p.m.` `AM/PM` differently.

[image: Setting on my Windows 10 machine]
[image: And the AM Symbol changed to AM now]
[image: Setting on a Windows 7 machine in comparison]
[image: And the AM Symbol is a.m. for the same Windows display language]
[image: And same setting on Windows 2012 in comparison which confirm that so far only windows 10 are different]

Also confirm that [DateTimeFormatInfo.AMDesignator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator(v=vs.110).aspx) for 'en-nz' now output 'AM' instead of 'a.m.'